# Visualize normals in third party application?

Tags: nvidia, directx-9

I am working on writing an exporter for 3D models which can be viewed in PDF (ie using PRC format), currently I am trying to figure out how to correctly write the normals to that format (which is not really explained very well in the spec). I created some very simple models (in OBJ) made of just a few triangles, with both perpendicular and non-perpendicular normals. However when I add the PRC to the PDF to view it in Adobe Reader, they look wrong (judging by how the light falls on them).

Now I would like to know if there are some kind of tools or debug utils which let me intercept the data as it is rendered by Adobe and somehow visualize the normals (or at least get the numbers)? I think if I can actually see which way the normals go (and if they indeed point in the correct hemisphere) then it might help me greatly to figure out how to encode the data correctly.

I am on Windows 10 and have an nvidia graphics card (GTX 970), and Adobe seems to use DirectX 9, and I use Visual Studio 2012 (but I also have installed VS 2015, just not using it for my projects (yet) as it seems to have a very high memory footprint).

This is an example of how one of my simple models is rendered in Adobe (purple) and also in my test app (showing normals in my app on top):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you grab the `vertex buffer` from Adobe you have to know its format to extract `normals`. So it seems like too complicated for such task.
Much faster is to guess the normal by color (assuming color is direct propotion of angle between `normal` and `light direction`).

[image]

Using [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color model:
Values (`V`) for points:

- N1: 58
- N2: 54
- N3: 15
- N4: 27
- N5: 14
- N6: 18

Using this values we can say:

1. Used Adobe Shader's color is not direct proportion of `Normal`. Maybe other visual style would be better.
2. `N6` ~ `N5` ~ `N3`. So I would swap normals `N6` and `N4`.
3. `N4` has different color (maybe value is wrong). Maybe you have to normalize them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah I have been testing like that so far, but the problem is that I have to write the normals to the file in spherical coordinates, limited to 0 < phi < pi/2 (same for theta), and (lossily) encode into an int16 plus a few bool flags (x-inverted, y-inverted, normal-inverted), and those flags and the conversion they expect are less than intuitive (the spec is really not much help). So what I have to do is encode it in a way I think might be right, then look at the results in Adobe and see if it seems right, so I had hoped there might be some way to intercept the renderer

Comment: Then try to search for `DirectX dll Injection` (if there is DX :) )

Comment: Ok will look for that, thanks :)
I had hoped there might be some tool out there which would let me visualize the normals so it would sort of "overlay" it or something, but I guess there is nothing out there like that.

Comment: As I mentioned it is impossible to find the `Normal` without knowing the `vertex` format. So there is no software :)

Comment: Yeah, well doing that (ie looking at it) and then also creating simple OBJs with normals that I made like what it seemed like, I finally figured out which way Adobe is really doing it (and once again it's different from the spec they gave). Anyway, I will mark this as correct answer, as this ultimately game me the answers I needed. Thanks

Comment: Good luck @MarkoT! BTW we have used `u3d` for `PDF 3D` (I didn't dare to repeat `PRC` from spec :).

Comment: Yeah the U3D, while still a pain in the arse, was relatively easy to implement, the PRC on the other hand feels a bit nightmarish, esp so many things different from spec, wrong in spec, not mentioned in spec... I assume you made an exporter for CAD data to U3D/PRC? Feel free to PM me if you like, if you need PRC info...